How come Yom Tov Kiddush can postpone having food on Yom Tov, specifically on Pesach?
What source in the Torah forbids a person from eating any food before Kiddush, specifically on Pesach and Chol Ha'Moed Pesach?

That's a general rule for kiddush. And what kiddush do you mean for Chol HaMoed?

Perhaps the OP is referring to shabbos chol hamoed

See Shulchan Aruch 271, which is based on Pesachim 106b
